# PostgreSQL Repeated Rows

Tags: php, postgresql

I am using php to retrieve PostgreSQL data from a table, the data cannot be repeated, I already have a way of getting data without repeated rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT realpath FROM paths WHERE fn='$fn'
```

what i need is a way of knowing which are the repeated rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with a as (
  SELECT count(1),realpath 
  FROM paths WHERE fn='$fn'
  GROUP BY realpath 
)
select realpath 
from a
where count > 1
```

**updtae**
As Abelisto suggested, my attempt to make it more clear using CTE might fail, so shorter and better way:

```
  SELECT count(1),realpath 
  FROM paths WHERE fn='$fn'
  GROUP BY realpath 
  HAVING count(1) > 1
```

Comment: Why not just use `having count(*) > 1`?

Comment: dunno. just thought it will be clearer to OP. of course having is shorter... I'll probably edit to have both, you are right